# NSView not being deallocated

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, delegation, nsviewcontroller

I've got a weird situation here that's almost certainly because I'm new to macOS development and I am missing some core knowledge.

I have a modal sheet that I'm displaying programmatically. (I'm not using a storyboard segue because it needs to be the result of a validation and so far I haven't seen a way to launch a segue programmatically - that's a sub-question here if anyone has advice)

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
searchVC = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "SearchSceneIdentifier") as? SearchViewController
    if searchVC != nil {
        searchVC!.searchTerm = searchTextField.stringValue
        self.presentAsSheet(searchVC!)
    }
```

This presents the sheet nicely and lets me interact with it. In it, I'm using a class which has a delegate in order to return asynchronous search queries.

Where this gets weird is that when I call

```
self.view.window!.close()
```

from inside the view controller, I don't think the view controller is getting deallocated. This seems to be because the delegate is still connected to it, even though the object that has this delegate is within the scope of the view controller itself. This delegate appears to be holding the view controller in memory.

I've gotten around this by doing this before closing the window:

```
search.delegate = nil
```

But this is not a good solution for other view controllers that have the same problem because they are inside windows and I don't want to have to catch the window closing then send some kind of notification to each in order to nil-ify their delegates.

Another approach that seems wrong as well is that I keep a reference to these windows in the application delegate and nil-ify it from there.

All of these seem like nasty solutions to the deallocation problem and my hope is that there is a cleaner way of doing this. In Objective-C, reference counts were always a problem but there were patterns to handle them cleanly.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: The documentation of `presentAsSheet(_:)` says "To dismiss the sheet, call the dismiss(_:) method on self (the presenting view controller).".

Comment: Indeed it does, thanks. But doing so without setting the delegate to nil causes the view controller to stay allocated and continue to receive delegate method calls.

Comment: Does the delegate own a link to the sheet? Or is there something else holding a strong link to the sheet?

Comment: From my testing, it seems like delegate is the only thing with a link. You use the word "strong" though - would this be solved by making the delegate a weak variable in its class? It's currently defined as 
    public var delegate : SearchDelegate?

Comment: How do you go from having a 'modal sheet' to having a delegate?

Comment: I have a search class which has the delegate property on it. The modal sheet containing the view that I'm discussing above receives messages from the search class by implementing the delegate's protocol and setting the delegate to 'self'.

Comment: your delegate property should be weak. This is a common scenario. Delegate properties should almost always be declared weak because of these kind of retain cycle issues.

Answer (score 0):

I updated all my delegates to `weak var` and that has solved all of my problems with deallocation.